# Iterating over files using Haskell

Tags: file, haskell, directory

I have a Haskell function that operates on a single file to produce a map. I want to iterate over all files in a directory and apply this function to produce a single map.

I am trying to approach it this way:

```
perFileFunc :: Int -> FilePath -> IO (Map.Map [Char] Double)

allFilesIn dir =  filter (/= "..")<$>(filter(/= ".")<$>(getDirectoryContents dir)
```

This gives me a list of all filenames in a directory except . and ..

Now when I try and do

```
myFunc dir n = map (perFileFunc n) <$> allFilesIn dir
```

It typechecks but doesn't do anything. I was expecting a list of maps which I would join using a unionWith (+) perhaps.

This doesn't seem to be the right way to do this.

Comment: Did you really intend `allFilesIn` to have _two_ arguments?

Comment: No I did not..my bad..edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tricky thing to understand about Haskell is how to recognize and compose IO actions. Let's look at some type signatures.

```
dir :: FilePath
allFilesIn :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
perFileFunc :: Int -> FilePath -> IO (Map.Map [Char] Double)
```

Now then, you said that for `myFunc`:

> I was expecting a list of maps

So for that function, you want the type signature

```
myFunc :: Int -> FilePath -> [Map.Map String Double]
```

Of course, the return type can't be *just* `[Map.Map String Double]`, because we need to perform some IO in order to evaluate `myFunc`. So given an `Int` and a `FilePath`, we actually want the return type to be an *IO action* that *produces* a `[Map.Map String Double]`:

```
myFunc :: Int -> FilePath -> IO [Map.Map String Double]
```

Now then, let's look at the IO actions we will be composing to create this function.

```
allFilesIn dir :: IO [FilePath]
perFileFunc n  :: FilePath -> IO (Map.Map String Double)
```

`perFileFunc` isn't actually an IO action, but it *is* a function that, given a `FilePath`, produces an IO action. So let's see...if we run the `allFilesIn` action, then we can work with that list and run `perFileFunc n` on each of its elements.

```
myFunc dir n = do
  files <- allFilesIn dir
  ???
```

So what goes in the `???` spot? We have a `[FilePath]` at our disposal, since we used `<-` to run the action `allFilesIn dir`. And we have a function, `perFileFunc n :: FilePath -> IO (Map.Map String Double)`. And we want the result to have the type `IO [Map.Map String Double]`.

Stop...Hoogle time! Generalizing the components we have (`a = FilePath`, `b = Map.Map String Double`), we [hoogle for `[a] -> (a -> IO b) -> IO [b]`](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+IO+b%29+-%3E+IO+%5Bb%5D) (pretending we haven't seen ehird's answer yet). Lo and behold, `mapM` is the magical solution we were looking for! (or `forM`, which is just `flip mapM`)

```
myFunc dir n = do
  files <- allFilesIn dir
  mapM (perFileFunc n) files
```

If you desugar this do notation, you'll find it reduces to ehird's answer:

```
myFunc dir n = allFilesIn dir >>= (\files -> mapM (perFileFunc n) files)
-- eta reduce (\x -> f x) ==> f
myFunc dir n = allFilesIn dir >>= mapM (perFileFunc n)
```

Comment: +1, mechanically deriving the correct answer is definitely the way to approach problems like this.

Answer (score 6):

Your code doesn't work properly because `(<$>)` is for lifting *pure* actions into an monadic (actually applicative) context, so your `myFunc dir n` is of type `IO [IO (Map.Map [Char] Double)]`; an IO action that, when executed, finds the list of files in a directory, and maps each one to another IO action that, when executed, produces the `Map` you want — without actually executing any of them. That's probably not what you want :)

You want to execute a function returning a monadic action over every element of a list, and return a list of the resulting values. That's what [mapM](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3amapM) does:

```
mapM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
```

So what you really want is:

```
myFunc dir n = allFilesIn dir >>= mapM (perFileFunc n)
```

You use `(>>=)` because `allFilesIn dir` is a monadic action itself, and you want to pass it to a function expecting its result type and returning another action (in this case, `mapM`).

Note that `mapM` is unlike `map` in that, in `IO` (not every monad behaves like this, but most do), it will execute every action before returning the list; this means that the result of every action must collectively fit into memory, and you won't be able to process the results incrementally. If you want that, you'll need something other than `mapM`, such as iteratees.